# How to properly scale an Image with PIL resize or transform on python

Tags: python, image, scale, python-imaging-library

I would like to know if you guys know how to properly scale an Image with PIL methods, Iǘe read and I know with:
    im.resize(size_tuple)
but I just keep getting my image incomplete once it is scale, here is my code and my pictures as result, hope you can help me, thanks

```
if image_size[0] <  120 and image_size[1] <  155:
     image = image.resize((120,155),Image.ANTIALIAS)
     image.save(f_out)
```

the code saves my resized image but it shows a black line at the bottom and the image is crop and not complete, any ideas how to solve this?, thanks in advance

UPDATE:
this is the complete code I'm using

```
def makeThumb(f_in, f_out, size=(120,155), pad=False):
    image = Image.open(f_in)
    avatar_size = (120,155)
    image_size = image.size
    method = Image.NEAREST if image_size == avatar_size else Image.ANTIALIAS

    if pad:
        thumb = image.crop( (0, 0, size[0], size[1]) )
        offset_x = max( (size[0] - image_size[0]) / 2, 0 )
        offset_y = max( (size[1] - image_size[1]) / 2, 0 )
        thumb = ImageChops.offset(thumb, offset_x, offset_y)

    else:
        if image_size[0] <  120 and image_size[1] <  155:
            image = image.resize((120,155),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image.save(f_out)          
        else:
            thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, size, method,0.05,(0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: Does your image contain transparency? Can you post an example somewhere?

Comment: It works for me. Is there something about how you open the image that's odd? Is it a JPEG or something else?

Comment: it is JPEG file I edit the code above to show all the code I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a bad version of PIL.  Your code exactly, run on your image (downloaded from your link) works for me.  That is: resizes filling the frame with no black bar.  I would try re-installing (or try another version) of your PIL module.

Comment: could you tell me which PIL version are you using so I could give a try, I'm using 2.6.1.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 (which is probably not relevant) and PIL 1.1.7 -- but PIL has many compile options and can depend on what libraries it is linked with, so this may not help you much.

Comment: Just to clarify the version numbers: 2.6.1 refers to [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.6.1) and 1.1.7 refers to [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). OP is using pillow (although this makes no difference on my machine - both PIL and pillow resize the image as expected) - suspect underlying jpeg library might be the cause.